# .NET 6, .NET 7, and .NET 8 required on webservers?

Tags: .net, .net-6.0, .net-7.0, .net-8.0

Our web servers at my workplace are currently at .NET 6.

Management has asked me to install .NET 8 when that becomes available and to REMOVE .NET 6... and NOT install .NET 7.

We have products compiled at 3.1, 5, and 6 right now, and have all .NET versions installed up to 6.

Does this make sense?

TO my understanding we still need the older versions of .NET on these servers for NuGet dependencies to run that are at older .NET levels.

It's free software, I don't see a downside to installing it anyway.

Can anyone confirm if there is any risk in SKIPPING or REMOVING .NET 6 or 7 and ONLY running .NET 8 on the web server?

Isn't that potentially going to break products that require older versions to run?

To management's mind, we should remove all the older versions and only have the latest version installed. To my mind that seems like a risk.

Comment: When you do a dry run of this process and test it on a non-production system, what happens?  Do the applications successfully run with only .Net 8 installed?

Comment: We haven't installed NET 8 yet.  The full release of NET 8 isn't out until Nov 14.  Testing is helpful, but its not confirmation.

Comment: You don't need the older runtimes unless your executable projects target them. An application only runs on a single runtime, even if some dependencies target an older one. If the older packages required missing functionality the build would fail even on development machines.  You can create a self-contained deployment for any .NET Core version to test how it behaves, you don't need to install the runtime on the build server

Answer (score 7):

> Does this make sense?

Sort of. I'll explain point by point.

> We have products compiled at 3.1, 5, and 6 right now, and have all .NET versions installed up to 6.

> Management has asked me to ... REMOVE .NET 6.

They didn't ask you to remove 3.1 or 5. Only 6. It would be a problem removing those other items if there are existing applications still using them.

There WILL be a problem removing 6 if there is an application still targeting it, but presumably this is in conjunction with updating those applications. This is an easy update for the developers to make — practically no required code changes from 6 to 8. Just install the new SDK, make a one-line config change in the project file, and rebuild it. *(This wasn't true prior to .NET 5, and getting from Framework up to 3.1 or 5 was a pain. But Core is a little more stable at the moment.)*

...assuming all your dependencies also support the new release. That *can* throw a wrench in the works. However, library authors are often testing against beta and release candidate builds in order to have support fairly quickly after the formal release.

In your shoes, I would make sure the development team is also aware of this management directive and install 8 as quickly as possible, then delay the removal step by a few weeks to ensure they have time to update the app.

> TO my understanding we still need the older versions of .NET on these servers for NuGet dependencies to run that are at older .NET levels.

That's not how it works. If an app targets .NET 6, and depends on a NuGet package that only supports up to .NET 5, the app will **fail to build**. You only need to worry about .NET versions actually targeted by the development team. Any NuGet packages they use will either support that version of .NET or they'll need to find another NuGet package to even be able to finish the app's build step, let alone deploy it to the server.

> It's free software, I don't see a downside to installing it anyway.

Sure there are: things like disk size, which also feeds into backup size and restore times. And environmental complexity. But the big one is security surface, as .NET 3.1 and 5 are formally end of life (no longer receive security patches!)

> Can anyone confirm if there is any risk in SKIPPING or REMOVING .NET 6 or 7 and ONLY running .NET 8 on the WebServer?

No risk in skipping 7, but as mentioned above there is risk in removing 6 too quickly.

> Isn't that potentially going to break products that require older versions to run?

Yes, but these are intended to be fast, easy updates most of the time. As long as the development team is aware of the mandate, you give them reasonable time to adjust, and you interpret the management directive in a way that allows for reasonable change management, you can do this.

> To management's mind, we should remove all the older versions and only have the latest version installed. To my mind that seems like a risk.

I agree there is risk. Latest releases sometimes have issues. I also agree with management. Since Core (and unlike with Framework), the .NET lifecycle is now short and you are expected to follow each new current (or long-term support/LTS) release fairly quickly. What I would hope to see is a 6 to 8 week lag following each new release for development testing before going to the new version.

What this means is you also need a real QA environment... really, at least 2 separate QA environments: 1 to mimic production, so you have a place ready to test "regular" application updates, and one that's allowed to vary from production where you can test things like .NET version upgrades and packaging deployments/changes.

Comment: As per my understanding, there are old Nuget packages(in each project) still referencing the .net core 3.1 and 5 versions, they will not work, it's always advisable to have backward software compatibility, please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: (though runtime issues can be present.) => this is my concern

Comment: My understanding is NuGet packages have to set what version(s) (can be more than one) of .Net they support, and the .Net build system will validate this. The trick is the definition is often "X version or higher", where it's theoretically possible for version X+1 to release and break this. Then the build would still be allowed and the issue wouldn't show until run time. But this is why we test and have QA.

Answer (score 2):

**I am extending my answer since I cannot paste the image into the comments
section above**

This is a very popular package and it only supports .net core 5.0. We are migrating
to .net core 8, which will not be supported by the Swashbuckle NuGet package.
[image]
[Note there are .net core 7 dependencies in the dependencies tab tho]

Comment: Don't use this one personally, but if you hover the mouse over the blue .NET 5.0 tag at the top, it shows ".NET 5.0 **or higher**" (same for .NET Core 3.0). It is also possible the package is no longer maintained, and later .Net versions introduced a breaking change, but the compatibility settings on the package indicate it should allow the build.

Comment: Additionally, when you look on the Dependencies tab, the listings under .NET 7 does not mean the package depends on .NET 7. It means, "When you use .NET 7, these are the dependencies the package will bring in." There is no .NET 8 because .NET 8 is not fully released yet, but I would expect the package to update to have a section for .NET 8 soon after its release.

Answer (score 0):

I want to thank you all for the great discussion.

I think this is a very important thing to talk about, but not many are talking about it.

This post from Microsoft seems to suggest it is safe to remove older NET versions, or to skip them:

[image]

[https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core#:~:text=After%20support%20ends%2C%20we%20recommend,and%20computing%20environment%20at%20risk](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core#:%7E:text=After%20support%20ends%2C%20we%20recommend,and%20computing%20environment%20at%20risk).

Though Microsoft says there's a risk in keeping the old versions, they don't comment on the risk in skipping levels.

I would assume removing a version would be in effect the same as skipping it.

I would prefer not to have to INFER my answers from what MS has to say.  I would prefer Microsoft actually wrote a clear answer.

But an inference is better than nothing...

What do you guys think?

Comment: Another interesting detail: If you install a new NET Level the installer does NOT REMOVE the old level. If the old level isn't needed then why MS is not removing that implicitly? MS does not even remove the same runtime level if you upgrade to higher minor NET Level version. I installed 7.0.403 on top of 7.0.401.. MS just allows them to install side by side. Why allow this if the old version is not needed?  Why Microsoft allows side by side installs if they earlier levels aren't needed?

Comment: Ya, to me that last point looks like Microsoft doesn't even trust their own runtime.  On the website they ask you to remove previous versions.. but the MS installer doesn't do that for you when you install a new NET level... Minor or Major version just leave existing builds installed.  Why Microsoft doesn't trust themselves to remove their own runtimes if not needed?

Comment: "If the old level isn't needed then why MS is not removing that implicitly?"  Because the installer for the new version doesn't know about any applications (plural) that might be using the old. You can have applications running both versions on the same system at the same time. Indeed this is **common**, because organizations will often update, test and deploy one application at a time when a new version is released. In this case, you need to keep the old .NET version until every application has migrated.

Comment: To supplement: remember, .NET is not embedded as part of an application, nor do applications register with the .NET runtime in any way. But applications are compiled to expect a specific version of .NET. (NuGet libraries can be configured to support a range of versions, but applications are compiled to a specific version). So when you install or update .NET, it has no way to know about anything else on the system that might still need the prior version.

Comment: OK, well, if that's the case then we do need to have all versions installed to ensure all applications that run on the webserver will work.  My original question asks if we can remove or omit level 6 or 7 and only install 8.  Can we expect 8 to run a .net 3.1, 6, or 7 application without that runtime installed?  Sounds like the answer is now "no?"

Comment: It is correct you need .NET 3.1 to run a 3.1 application, 6 to run a 6 application etc, but again: **the expectation is you know about the applications you are running**, and you take the time to also update them to use the new versions, rather than continuing to run (and keep) the old version. And again: the code changes required for this are minimal to even none. Just install the new SDK on the build machine, update one line in the project file, and rebuild the app. This is **important**, because the old versions stop getting security updates much more quickly now.

Comment: Yes, well, there are too many products to update them all in one night and push them through a pipeline to production in my case.  I think after everything is upgraded safely we can remove 3.1, 6, and 7.  I think that was your earlier strategy: keep the old versions for a few months to ensure everything works at level 8.  My company is asking me to omit levels if they aren't already there and remove any earlier levels that are there.  My company thinks 8 is magical and will run any app built at any level.

Comment: Months? Maybe weeks. And you can definitely still omit 7 and go straight to 8 if nothing so far is using it. The big other thing to really take home here is it's **not okay** to still be using 3.1 or 5 at all, because they represent potential security concerns. But you're not alone in being behind in that area. The change to Core represented a change in _the whole philosophy_ of application support lifecycles that just hasn't been absorbed everywhere.